# Change color of all links with class X JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors

[Link with example](http://www.ufilme.ro/index/lista_seriale_online/0-16)

I am using the following function:

```
<div align="center"><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('A'); return false;">A</a>
<script>
    function changeColor(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#FFF"; // forecolor
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // backcolor
    }
</script>
```

When, for example, I click on A on the page with the example, only the first link is changing colors because the script is changing colors by id.  How can I change all link colors by class?

What I want is when I click on A, all links with class A should change their color, and when I click B, all links with class B should change their color, etc.

Comment: you're only using javascript, not jquery. change your tag.

Comment: with javascript alone? or a library like jQuery?

Comment: use CSS and toggle a class on click event, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function changeColor( _class ) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( _class );
    for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
        elems[i].style.color = "#FFF";
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVagh/5/)

Change the function to the above, and pass a class to it instead ?

jQuery version:

```
$('div[align="center"] > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.' + $.trim($(this).text())).css({color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#ff0000'});
});
```

with HTML

```
<div align="center"><a href="#">A</a></div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVagh/4/)

Comment: It's supported in just about every browser, except IE8 and below, which doesn't really have much support for classes anyway.

Comment: **+1** for providing JS solution, and your last comment `;)`.

Comment: i tried it but had no  impact [link](http://www.ufilme.ro/index/lista_seriale_online/0-16)

Comment: hmm still doesn't work so i want when a users clicks on A or B or C .. all links with Class A or B or C to change their color :|

Comment: Ok it worked can you add also the option to change text decoration to none , i tried but it didn't worked

Comment: also this is optional .. when i click to A all links with color A change to red .. after i click to B all link with B change to red and links a get to default ?

Comment: @VicToRSava - That would require some more markup, say for instance a common class for all the links that can be used to remove the styles, and if  you're trying to change many styles you should just add another class etc.